# Is it a good practice to use Room to store links to binary files alongside with metadata?

Tags: java, android

I'd like to know your opinion on the following: Say you have multiple structured binary files (many many hundreds) and a library to work with them (create, open, read, save). How would you design an android application to wrap it all up:

- `Would you pack all the binary files in the Zip archive` **or** `leave files separate in the application directory (subdirectory)`;
- `Would you use Room library to create links (Uri) to those files along with additional information like tags, titles, thumbnail images (also Uri)` **or** `access them directly and save the extra in metafiles` **or** `create a extra binary layer for each of the files to store the metadata (binaryWithMeta <- (metadata + binary))`

Answer (score 4):

1) Room is just a wrapper around SQLite, and you're in luck, they asked and answered the BLOB performance question already.

> ## Internal Versus External BLOBs in SQLite
>
> The matrix below shows the time needed to read BLOBs stored in separate files divided by the time needed to read BLOBs stored entirely in the database. Hence, for numbers larger than 1.0, it is faster to store the BLOBs directly in the database. For numbers smaller than 1.0, it is faster to store the BLOBs in separate files.
>
> [image]
>
> We deduce the following rules of thumb from the matrix above:
>
> - A database page size of 8192 or 16384 gives the best performance for large BLOB I/O.
> - **For BLOBs smaller than 100KB, reads are faster when the BLOBs are stored directly in the database file. For BLOBs larger than 100KB, reads from a separate file are faster.**
>
> Of course, **your mileage may vary** depending on hardware, filesystem, and operating system. **Double-check these figures on target hardware** before committing to a particular design.

Source: https://www.sqlite.org/intern-v-extern-blob.html, emphasis mine.

As you can see SQLite is perfectly fine for storing metadata, even image thumbnails.

2) Answers to your other questions depend on multiple factors:

- file size (maybe compress large files, maybe put small files in the database)
- file type (don't compress MP3s, JPGs, etc.)
- frequency of access (don't compress often accessed files, or cache them),
- whether you have to support low end devices with low storage or RAM, ...

Yes, there will need to be some sort of abstraction layer to optimally handle different kinds of files in different kinds of conditions. There's no one good answer.

Expect possible opinionated answers which are frowned upon here on Stack Overflow.

Comment: I know that Room is the wrapper, but thanks for the matrix. Also, the structured binaries that I mentioned are all custom and of the same type.

Comment: What an amazing answer. Above and beyond. This site is epic